# Reordenar una tabla acorde al valor de sus columnas

Tags: r

Dada una tabla como esta:

```
       df:
       Habitat           Spp_site           Spp           Site   NGS      RT-PCR
        Crop           Amaranthus_M2V      Amaranthus      M2V    1         1
        Crop           Amaranthus_M3V      Amaranthus      M2V    1         0
        Crop           Convolvulus_M1V     Convolvulus     M1V    0         0
        Wasteland      Convolvulus_E1P     Convolvulus     E1P    1         1
        Oak            Convolvulus_Q2P     Convolvulus     Q2P    1         1
        Oak            Anchusa_Q1P         Anchusa         Q1P    0         1
```

Me gustaría comprimir esta tabla en base a los datos de la columna de NGS Y RT-PC, obteniendo un output como este:

```
   df_out:
    Spp          Habitat           NGS         RTPCR
    Amaranthus    Crop             2/2          1/2
    Convolvulus   Crop             0/1          0/1
    Convolvulus   Wasteland        1/1          1/1
    Convolvulus   Oakwood          1/1          1/1
    Anchusa       Oakwood          0/1          1/1
```

La columna NGS daría es el número de spp que se ha secuenciado frente al total de esa especie,teniendo en cuenta de cada hábitat son. Por otro lado la columna RT-PCR sería valor RT-PCR frente al total.

No encuentro la manera de hacer esto.
Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo estos datos:

```
df <- read.table(text="Habitat           Spp_site           Spp           Site   NGS      RT-PCR
Crop           Amaranthus_M2V      Amaranthus      M2V    1         1
Crop           Amaranthus_M3V      Amaranthus      M2V    1         0
Crop           Convolvulus_M1V     Convolvulus     M1V    0         0
Wasteland      Convolvulus_E1P     Convolvulus     E1P    1         1
Oak            Convolvulus_Q2P     Convolvulus     Q2P    1         1
Oak            Anchusa_Q1P         Anchusa         Q1P    0         1", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df
    Habitat        Spp_site         Spp Site NGS RT.PCR
1      Crop  Amaranthus_M2V  Amaranthus  M2V   1      1
2      Crop  Amaranthus_M3V  Amaranthus  M2V   1      0
3      Crop Convolvulus_M1V Convolvulus  M1V   0      0
4 Wasteland Convolvulus_E1P Convolvulus  E1P   1      1
5       Oak Convolvulus_Q2P Convolvulus  Q2P   1      1
6       Oak     Anchusa_Q1P     Anchusa  Q1P   0      1
```

**Importante**: nota el nombre de la columna `RT-PCR` deberías modificarla por un nombre menos ambiguo, en este caso se hizo automáticamente y se renombró como `RT.PCR`

Con `dplyr` se puede plantear una solución bastante simple, que dependerá de la cantidad de columnas que tengas:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Habitat, Spp) %>% 
  summarize(NGS = paste(sum(NGS),n(),sep="/"),
            RT.PCR = paste(sum(RT.PCR),n(),sep="/")
            )

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Habitat [3]
  Habitat   Spp         NGS   RT.PCR
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr> <chr> 
1 Crop      Amaranthus  2/2   1/2   
2 Crop      Convolvulus 0/1   0/1   
3 Oak       Anchusa     0/1   1/1   
4 Oak       Convolvulus 1/1   1/1   
5 Wasteland Convolvulus 1/1   1/1
```

El truco es agrupar por `Habitat` y `Spp` para luego "sumarizar" cada columna, en cuanto a los valores que buscas a) La cantidad de filas del grupo b) la suma de los valores

Comment: Perdona por la demora Patricio, no he tenido tiempo a valorar el script, este funciona a la perfección para lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias